# Brainfuck - интерпретатор на Python

Tags: python-3.x, brainfuck

> Напишите интерпретатор практически полноценного языка "Взрыв мозга".
>
> Условия те же, что и в предыдущей задаче, но добавлены целых две новые команды: «[» и «]». В корректной программе всегда соблюдается парность скобок — все открытые скобки закрыты, нет «висящих» ни открытых, ни закрытых скобок, каждой открытой скобке соответствует своя закрытая. Эти команды делают порядок выполнения команд более сложным.
>
> Открывающая скобка велит произвести проверку: равно ли нулю число в клетке, на которой в этот момент находится машинка? Если да, то нужно «перепрыгнуть» вперёд по тексту программы (не по ленте с числами!) до клетки, следующей за соответствующей закрывающей скобкой. Если нет, нужно просто выполнить следующую команду (т. е. войти в кусок программы, находящийся внутри данной пары скобок). Закрывающая же скобка возвращает выполнение программы к соответствующей открывающей скобке.
>
> Таким образом, команды «[» и «]» реализуют цикл. Например, сочетание команд «[-]» уменьшает значение текущей ячейки до тех пор, пока оно не станет равно нулю, после чего программа выполняется дальше, т. е. обнуляет ячейку.
>
> Удивительно, но если снять ограничение на длину ленты, то на языке "Взрыв мозга" можно реализовать буквально любой алгоритм.
>
> ## Формат ввода
>
> Вводится одна строка, состоящая только из символов «>», «<», «+», «-», «.», «[», «]» — программа на языке "Взрыв мозга". Гарантируется, что парность скобок соблюдена.
>
> ## Формат вывода
>
> Выводятся несколько целых чисел в соответствии с командами программы.
>
> ### Пример
>
> ## Ввод:

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```

> ## Вывод

```
72
101
108
108
111
32
87
111
114
108
100
33
10
```

Не могу разобраться с задачей, она работает не совсем корректно.
Мой код:

```
tape = [0 for _ in range(30001)]
position = 0
f = False
s = False
for cmd in input():
    test = tape[position]
    if cmd == '[':
        f = True
    elif f and not s and cmd == '-':
        tape[position] = 1
    elif cmd == ']':
        s = True
    if f and s:
        f = False
        s = False
    elif cmd == '>':
        position += 1   
    elif cmd == '<':
        position -= 1
    elif cmd == '+':
        tape[position] += 1
    elif cmd == '-':
        tape[position] -= 1
    elif cmd == '.':
        print(tape[position])
    if tape[position] > 255:
        tape[position] = 0
    elif tape[position] < 0:
        tape[position] = 255
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что что-то работает «не совсем корректно»?

Comment: ++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>. В этом примере некорректный ответ

Comment: Исправил вопрос